# What happens to emails being sent to orgwide address 'Return-Path' value

Tags: email, apex-email-service

Some of our customers are replying to the 'Return-Path' value of emails being sent out by us (most likely through their email client or server settings, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542182/why-is-my-customer-seeing-the-return-path-address-rather-than-the-from-address))

I'd like to know what actually happens to emails being sent to these addresses (ending in something like `@2vamea4dqion.b-kz04eac.eu2.bnc.salesforce.com`)
I can't seem to find any EmailMessages being created for them, so I want to find out if it's in any way possible to 'intercept' these messages at some point so they can still be processed.